# Как прописать ввод с клавиатуры в TextField и в javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Пишу программу с использованием javafx, в ней нужно вводить данные в одно поле TextField, после подсчёта выводить в другое. 
В консоли это бы выглядело примерно так:

```
Scaner scaner = new Scaner(System.in);
int a = scaner.nextInt;
int b = scaner.nextInt;
int c = a + b;
System.out.print(c);
```

У меня вопрос, как сделать ввод и вывод в графическом интерфейсе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде Batton нужно создать переменную private TextField result (над этой строкой необходимо прописать @FXML), предварительно в файле sample.fxml, прописать fx:id="result" в строке <"TextField>, чтобы получилось <"TextField fx:id="result"> ("result" - имя переменной). Далее, в методе, отвечающим за выполнения кода Batton присвоить переменную "result" нужной переменной, например:

```
String str = String.valueOf(result.getText());
double h = Double.parseDouble(result.getText());
```

Ввод в Вашем примере:

```
 int a = Integer.parseInt(result.getText());
 int b = Integer.parseInt(result.getText());
```

Вывод выглядит примерно так:

```
int c = a+b;
result.setText(String.valueOf(c));
```